# Chrome console - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.engines is not iterable

Tags: angular, google-chrome-console

This error appears in chrome console when I load the app file on localhost:4200.
I cannot figure out what does this point to. How do I find out the source of this error in my code?

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.engines is not iterable
    at E.updateSocialMedia (content.js:48)
    at new E (content.js:48)
    at Function.start (content.js:48)
    at Function.main (content.js:48)
```

[image]

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with your project. Just check the extensions on your browser to find out if any of them has caused the problem.

Answer (score 31):

In my case McAfee chrome extension was causing the problem.
[McAfee extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWVsF.png)

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.engines is not iterable
    at E.updateSocialMedia (content.js:48)
    at new E (content.js:48)
    at Function.start (content.js:48)
    at Function.main (content.js:48)
```

When I disabled the extension, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Thank you. It work for me also. I don't even remember installing that extension.

Comment: I had the same error and removing McAfee fixed it as well.